# Retrieving and re-saving an nsmutablearray to nsuserdefaults from a uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have a uitableview with a list of items populated from a JSON file located locally within the app. Everything works as far as getting the list to the table and the multiple selection of items which when selected (or deselected) are then saved to a nsmutablearray.

The problem is when the user leaves the view and returns and selects another item (or deselects a currently selected item). At this point the mutable array is then empty.

I'm not sure if the nsuserdefaults saving of the mutable array is the problem. it saves it fine but then when the view reappears (the mutable array's value is fine at this point) and the user touches a table row the array is null once more.

my .h file:

```
@interface CategoriesViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSMutableArray *_selectedItems;

    NSString *filePath;

    NSString *string;

}

// arForTable array will hold the JSON results from the api
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arForTable;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *categorySelected;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *jsonStringCategory;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *accessoryView;

@end
```

my .m file:

```
@implementation CategoriesViewController
@synthesize arForTable = _arForTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.categorySelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self reloadMain];

    // assignment reference so don't release
     _selectedItems = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] selectedCategories];

    self.tableView.hidden = NO;

}

-(void) reloadMain {

    // countrySaved value from NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults * defaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *countryString = [defaults stringForKey:@"selectedCountryTableString"];
    NSString *cityString = [defaults stringForKey:@"selectedCityTableString"];
    NSLog(@"countrystring from category is %@", countryString);
    NSLog(@"citystring from category is %@", cityString);

    // getting path to the file

    if ([defaults stringForKey:@"selectedCountryTableString"] == NULL) {

        filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categoriesit" ofType:@"json"];

    } else if ([countryString isEqualToString:@"UK"]) {

        filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categoriesuk" ofType:@"json"];

    } else if ([countryString isEqualToString:@"Italy"]) {

        filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categoriesit" ofType:@"json"];

    } else if ([countryString isEqualToString:@"Spain"]) {

        filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categorieses" ofType:@"json"];

    } else if ([countryString isEqualToString:@"Brazil"]) {

        filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categoriesbr" ofType:@"json"];
    }


    NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    //NSLog(@"File content: %@", fileContent);

    // creating new parser
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

    // parsing the first level
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];
    NSDictionary *menu = (NSDictionary *) [data objectForKey:@"menu"];

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"menu is %@",menu);
#endif

    NSMutableArray *itemsTMP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:nil];

    // NSLog(@"results File test %@",dict);

    itemsTMP = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];
    // NSLog(@"itemsTMPitemsTMP File test %@",itemsTMP);

    self.arForTable = [itemsTMP copy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arForTable count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];

        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:55.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    }

    UIImageView *cellAccessoryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png"]] ;
    UIImageView *cellAccessoryNoneImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]] ;


    if([_selectedItems containsObject:indexPath]){
        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryImageView;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryNoneImageView;
    }

    // Get item from tableData
    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[_arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // encoding fix

    NSString *correctStringTitle = [NSString stringWithCString:[[item objectForKey:@"key"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    cell.textLabel.text = [correctStringTitle capitalizedString];

    NSNumber *num = [item objectForKey:@"id"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [num stringValue];

    cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSUserDefaults * defaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if([_selectedItems containsObject:indexPath]){
        [_selectedItems removeObject:indexPath];

        [self.categorySelected removeObject:[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];

        string = [self.categorySelected componentsJoinedByString:@","];


        [defaults setObject:string forKey:@"selectedCategoryTableString"];

        NSLog(@"%@ defaults from did select remove categorySelected",[defaults stringForKey:@"selectedCategoryTableString"]);

        NSLog(@"%@ STRING FROM contains / removeObj",string);

    } else {

        [_selectedItems addObject:indexPath];

        [self.categorySelected addObject:[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];

        NSUserDefaults * defaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        string = [self.categorySelected componentsJoinedByString:@","];

        [defaults setObject:string forKey:@"selectedCategoryTableString"];

        NSLog(@"%@ providerSelected from did select add ",self.categorySelected);

        NSLog(@"%@ STRING FROM contains / addObj",string);

    }

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    //      [tableView reloadData];
}


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:NO];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;

    NSUserDefaults * defaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 //   NSLog(@"ALL DEFAULTS %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);

    NSLog(@"%@ defaults from view appear categorySelected",[defaults stringForKey:@"selectedCategoryTableString"]);

    string = [defaults stringForKey:@"selectedCategoryTableString"];


    NSLog(@"%@ STRING from will appear",string);

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

also in the app delegate I have in the .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedCategories;
```

and in the .m:

```
 `_selectedCategories = [NSMutableArray new];
```

in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

just to be clear:

when the view appears again (if I nslog the output) the mutablearray has been saved and is retrieved correctly. the mutable array only clears itself when a tablerow is touched again. 
thanks if anyone can help with this. I've been stuck on it for some time...

Comment: I don't see you synchronizing your defaults after writing to them.  Make sure you call `-synchronize` on your saved `NSUserDefaults` instance.

Comment: thanks! I just added  [defaults synchronize]; still the same thing. it does save the array. the result is accessible in other view controllers and this view controller too when it re-appears. it just gets wiped out when select table row method is called. (it was saving it before the synchronize too)

Comment: As you are using `NSUserDefaults` only as a storage at `CategoriesViewController`, it will make more sense to check `selectedCategories` content at `viewWillAppear:` - you'll overwrite the data at `NSUserDefaults` anyway. The code inside `CategoriesViewController` looks fine in terms of not erasing `selectedCategories`, it might be changed by other objects though. Try global search of `.selectedCategories` and double check child controllers do not mess with it (if, as I understood, they are supposed to read data from `NSUserDefaults`).

Comment: you said you added `[default synchronize]` … could you edit your example to show where.

Comment: can you please clarify __which__ mutablearray has been saved and retrieved correctly?  It is very unclear in your question

Comment: I believe I have solved your problem, most likely #3 in my edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit**

```
// DONT EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER DO THIS!!!
//  We don't use types as variable names, that is implicit...
//  I get it, this is a string, BUT WHAT IS IT A STRING OF, the name
//  'string' does you, and anyone else, no good.  Think about all your 
//  code like you are writing it for someone else, because when you come
//  back to it in 6 months, you will be someone else, and you won't know
//  what this means
NSString *string;
```

**end edit**

I would not be using NSUserDefaults this way.  You have already parsed JSON into an archiveable object (NSMutableArray).  In viewDidLoad, you should probably try doing something like:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     // Load the array from a plist file
     self.dataYouNeed = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"someFileName.plist"];
     // If we got back nil, that file didn't exist, so call 'reloadMain',
     //  do your parsing there THEN SAVE to a plist using:
     //
     // [myArray writeToFile:@"someFileName.plist"]
     //
     if(self.dataYouNeed == nil) [self reloadMain];

     // Then do the exact same thing when you try to persist your selection...
     //  aka do not store a CSV string, just store an Array, and call writeToFile:
     //  when you want to save, and arrayWithContentsOfFile when you want to read 
     //  it back in

}
```

On top of that, depending on where your data is coming from, I would move all of your data out of the JSON files and set it up in a plist, then you can ditch all of your parsing code.... :).  Basically I am saying this is all a little too complicated for such a simple task, make your own life easier.

**edit**

You may have an issue with not using 'self.string',  simply referring to 'string' is dangerous, you are creating a new reference everytime.  This is most likely creating a memory leak. (ARC is not magic, it can not handle ALL memory management for you)

**edit**

Ok, so re-reading your code, I noticed a few things.

### 1. Why do you store your CSV string in the 'string' instance var?

This is somewhat redundant.  At no point do you ever read from this variable without having set it in the few lines of code before.  It should just be an NSString declared with in the scope of the method.

### 2. Are you expecting '_selectedItems' to have retained your reference to the 'selectedCategories' array on your AppDelegate?

You can not make this assumption, especially without having made a @property declaration.  ARC does not know how to handle it and will probably be releasing the reference when you leave the view.  The more likely possibility is that you are creating a memory leak every time you set that variable.  You can also not guarantee that viewDidLoad will be called again to reset the reference.  You should probably be setting this in viewWillAppear.

### 3. Which NSMutableArray are you experiencing a nil reference to?

If it is '_selectedItems', consider #2.  If it is 'categorySelected', this is also probably being released when this view disappears.  If this is really what you are trying to persist, then why are you not populating it from the viewDidAppear method.  The only thing you do in viewDidAppear is set the 'string' variable (which is never actually read from, like #1 says).  Did you mean to set 'categorySelected' here?  I believe you meant to get your list from NSUserDefaults, then populate 'categorySelected' using that string's componentsSeparatedByString: method, which returns an array

Answer (score 3):

Every time a user goes to some other view and comes back then 
`self.categorySelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` gets executed resulting it to an empty array.

Comment: if I comment that out then I get null for the mutable array with no objects adding to it.

Comment: Dont comment, first try that with a global array. If it works then use a shared/singleton class for that.

Comment: @AKV with the global array would I still have     categorySelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in the viewController? I added the global array but no luck

Comment: then you need to check if(!categorySelected) { categorySelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; }. Means if its object is not there create one, if object exists dont create.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya when the view appears again (if I nslog the output) the mutablearray has been saved and retrieved correctly. It only clears itself when a tablerow is touched again.

Comment: Now this issue is ios specific, and i no not more than ABC of ios. :(

Answer (score 3):

First serialize the array when leaving the view:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:@[@"1",@"2",@"3"]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"myarray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then deserialize it when you are back to that view:

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myarray"];
NSArray *myarray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"MYARRAY %@", myarray);
```

Note: if key is not found then init a new array.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to change 'retain' to 'strong' here?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *categorySelected;
```

Comment: retain and strong very similar in ARC

Comment: thanks for catching the missing synthesize. I added that but still the same issue persists...

Comment: @synthesize is not required in new compiler, it is already there (Hidden).

Comment: And if you try to change this in your App Delegate:  _selectedCategories = [NSMutableArray new];

For a proper initialization:
_selectedCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: @apascua no luck with that change in initialization unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is, you are setting the `selectedItems` array in `viewDidLoad` method. Probably the `viewDidLoad` is working once.

Just add the following line in your `viewWillAppear` method:

```
_selectedItems = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] selectedCategories];
```

Comment: thanks! I tried that to no avail. I guess I'm going to use plists instead. I think I was over complicating things...